# How can I add Loading Overlay to Flutter App, "Android"?

Tags: flutter

Am working on my first Flutter app.
When I click the app to start it, before it takes me to the home page, there is this small loading time and the screen is white.

How can I add a Loading overlay screen during the loading time?
And is there a simple loading overlay that comes with Flutter to import and I can use when the screen is loading to show some better looking screen than this white screen I got?

I just wrote a simple Flutter app which has a home page. But while the app is loading, it just shows a blank white screen and after few seconds it takes me to the home page.